# docusign not accepting duplicates

Tags: docusignapi

For testing purposes, we are creating contacts with the same name but with a different email address and with separate application and contract mapped to the contact. But in the DocuSign status object, when we researched, we found that the DocuSign is picking the contact which was created earlier and not the latest contact (which is supposed to pick the latest).

Hence, for sending emails and status to an external system it takes the value from the old contact and not the new one

Did anyone face the same issue? If not, can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Where and how are you creating the contacts?

Comment: What DocuSign status object are you referring to? Are you using DocuSign for Salesforce or the base DocuSign product?

Comment: We are creating the contacts from our UI and mapping as a new contact in the Salesforce.

Comment: We are using the DocuSign for Salesforce and am referring to the DocuSign Status object in DocuSign for Salesforce.